# How can I get my Durable Function activities to inherit the tracing id of the HttpTrigger that started it?

Tags: c#, open-telemetry, azure-durable-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have an Azure functions C# project. In the startup I have the following

```cs
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
```

I then have an HTML trigger function...

```cs
    [Function("delete-message")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
        HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient durableClient)
    {
        _ = await durableClient
            .ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                orchestratorName: DeleteMessageOrchestrator.OrchestratorId,
                payload);
        retun ........;
    }
}
```

These are appearing as completely unrelated in Application Insights. How can I ensure the activity context continues to be used so I can see my orchestrated Durable Function executions nested inside the HttpTrigger that scheduled them?